# SQL Select Query (extended)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, search

I am searching for a proper SQL query which would allow me the following:

- In the database I have an article which contains word "tax"
- If I use query `SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE content LIKE '%tax%'` it will find my article
- However if I search for "import tax", it will not find anything

Is there something what I overlooked what could still return my article even with this "extended" search phrase?

Thank you, 
Ivana

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Does your article contains the substring "import tax"? Are you sure it is just a single space between import and tax?

Comment: or hidden characters

Comment: I have a search input what takes anything you write into in to finish the search query. The structure of the final query is "SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE content LIKE '%inserted value here%'". Problem is that query takes the entire input as a fixed value and compares it to the content of the table 'table'. If this input (in the exact form - "import tax") is not there, it will return nothing. However, if divided into smaller entities, word "tax" would be found.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use my sql text based search as

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH (content) AGAINST ('your_search_text' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

You can check this here [mysql full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for multiple values, you can use regular expressions:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE content REGEXP 'import|tax'
```

This searches for content that has both "import" and "tax".

I would also suggest that you look into full text indexes.  However, be careful, because "tax" has three characters and that might not be long enough to make it into the full text index using the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use another like:

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' 
WHERE content LIKE '%tax%' AND content LIKE '%import%';
```